# How to check does object is not first or last in array but there are duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with 10 objects.

When I open some object in popup need to know does next or previous object in array are last or first in the array.

And If is first or last in array, need to disable next or previous buttons.

Problem is cus some of docs have the same ID, and I checking index of an object by ID:

`const index = documents.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);`

And then if I have the first and fourth object in the array with the same ID, it will return index: 0, always:

How to make this work as expected?

This array is just example:

```
documents = [
 {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
 {id: '2', name: '2'},
 {id: '3', name: '3'},
 {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
 {id: '4', name: '4'},
 {id: '5', name: '5'}
]
```

Later I use `index` to disable or enable previous or next button.

Comment: `index` should be `3` of `id: Test1`?

Comment: Yes, but `documents.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);` will return `index: 0` always

Answer (score 2):

*you can use .filter to get all values of id you want,
for example:*

```
let documents = [
  {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
  {id: '2', name: '2'},
  {id: '3', name: '3'},
  {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
  {id: '4', name: '4'},
  {id: '5', name: '5'}
 ];
const things = documents.filter((documents) => documents.name === id)

console.log(things)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
documents.map(doc => (

 if(doc===documents[documents.length-1]) || (doc===documents[0]) { 

   // apply the code for disabling next and prev buttons
   }
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.indexOf()` to find the index of the current item by reference:

```js
const documents = [{"id":"TEST1","name":"TEST1"},{"id":"2","name":"2"},{"id":"3","name":"3"},{"id":"TEST1","name":"TEST1"},{"id":"4","name":"4"},{"id":"5","name":"5"}];

const current = documents[3];

const index = documents.indexOf(current);

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `findIndex` returns the index of the **first element in the array** that satisfies the provided testing function.

So you can use `lastIndexOf`:

```
const result = documents.map(s=> s.id).lastIndexOf(find);
```

An example:

```js
let documents = [
  {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
  {id: '2', name: '2'},
  {id: '3', name: '3'},
  {id: 'TEST1', name: 'TEST1'},
  {id: '4', name: '4'},
  {id: '5', name: '5'}
 ];

 let find = 'TEST1';

 const result = documents.map(s => s.id).lastIndexOf(find);
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: But I don't know which is next or prev `object value` data are changing dynamically

Comment: @MarkJames could you clarify please what you mean? Do you know your id?

Comment: I know the ID of the currenty opened object. 
And by that ID i find the current index. 
And then I reduce or increase for one index value, to get next or prev documents. 
Problem is cus in array I can have 2 or more the totally same objects.

Comment: @MarkJames could you write the test cases and it will be really helpful to understand what you want